# How to set a transparent border button

Tags: android, button, transparent

I'm trying to set a transparent `button`, I create a layout `camera` and one `button` overlay the preview, but the `button` is orbed and I see a square background border. How can get off this border?

---

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/camera_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_buton" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Thx a lot

Comment: u need to set transparent bg for that

Comment: are you sure you are not mixing background with border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this element in your button:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

Add `android:background="#00000000"` to your button element

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#00000000" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a drawable file to set for background in which fill solid color whatever you want and make stroke color transparent and then set this file as your button bacground.

xml code is somewhat like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#e1e1e1" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to add an image over your button. So that it looks like a camera icon and is clickable as well. (Pardon me if not.)

You should then consider, using ImageButton which exactly does what you want. A Button with a **src** attribute to set an Image which appears on top of the button.

[An example.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/)

Also, incase you wanna show only image but not the border at all, then you can directly use an ImageView which supports click events. :)